# How do I diagnose problems docker deployments (dokku/git push)?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new to Docker and dokku, and DigitalOcean, and just trying to figure out how all the pieces fit together. I'm deploying my app  with git.  When I deploy, it seems to succeed from my end, but when I log in and look for the running process with docker ps, I don't see any.

A little investigation shows it tried to do something...

```
# docker ps -a 
ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS 
e69021b44e45 app/foo:latest /bin/bash -c /start 12 minutes ago Exit 0
```

Trying to launch manually:

```
# docker run e69021b44e45 node app.js 
Unable to find image 'e69021b44e45' (tag: latest) locally 
Pulling repository e69021b44e45 
2013/09/21 04:12:02 Internal server error: 404 trying to fetch remote history for e69021b44e45
```

What could I be doing wrong, and how do I investigate issues like this?

For more information, I'm deploying to Docker using dokku on DigitalOcean's Ubuntu/Docker image.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the proper way to address the container is 'app/foo:latest', not `e69021b44e45`. Now that I've got that sorted, I can use `# docker run app/foo:latest /app/bin/node /app/app.js` and see the error that caused the process to stop.